# Element is no longer valid

Tags: python, selenium

I face a problem with Python and Selenium.

I want to click a link, this is my Py code:

```
toubao_luru_xpath='//div[87]/xml/items/item[2]/item[@path=policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp]'
#url=policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp
print WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,toubao_luru_xpath)))
print browser.find_element_by_xpath(toubao_luru_xpath)
#print browser.find_element_by_xpath(toubao_luru_xpath).click()
```

The error is:

> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
>   line 80, in until
>         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)     selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Yes,

And this is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none"><xml id=__menu>
<items>
    <item  name="quotation"  label="&#25955;&#21333;&#25253;&#20215;" >
       <item  name="input"  label="&#24405;&#20837;"  path="policyquotation/createquotation/chooseproduct.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/1.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="quotationinput"  label="&#24405;&#20837;"  icon="../image/icon/1.gif"  visible="false"  command="commandCreateQuotationTemplate" ></item>
        <item  name="quotationinput2014"  label="&#24405;&#20837;"  path="policyquotation_v2/chooseproduct2014.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/1.gif" ></item>
        <item  name="enterquotation"  label="enterquotation"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="queryQuotation"  label="&#26597;&#35810;"  path="policyquotation/qryquotationlist.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/2.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="queryQuotation2"  label="&#26597;&#35810;"  path="policyquotation_v2/qryquotationlist.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/2.gif" ></item>
        <item  name="packageWork"  label="&#22871;&#39184;&#25351;&#23450;"  path="policyquotation/package-manage-work.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/3.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="querypackage"  label="&#22871;&#39184;&#31649;&#29702;"  path="policyquotation/query-package-list.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/4.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="quotationfollow"  label="&#25253;&#20215;&#36319;&#36827;"  path="policyquotation/followquotation.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/5.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="entererror"  label="entererror"  path="error.jsp"  visible="false" ></item>
        <item  name="quotationfollownew"  label="&#25253;&#20215;&#36319;&#36827;"  path="policyquotation_v2/followquotation.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/5.gif"  visible="false" ></item>
    </item>
    <item  name="application"  label="&#25237;&#20445;" >
        <item  name="input"  label="&#24405;&#20837;"  path="policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp"  icon="../image/icon/1.gif" ></item>
</html>
```

The last `<item>` I want to click

Comment: use this xPath `//item[@path='policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp']`

Comment: provide `html` code of target element

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's unique given the HTML you provided and I'm assuming that there aren't two links to the same URL so it should be good.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("item[path='policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp']").click()
```

Comment: the user is instantiating it with browser instead of driver. `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("item[path='policynewbiz/inputapplication/chooseproduct.jsp']").click()`